# Metric for a set of skew lines in three dimensional space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose we have a set $M = \left\{\boldsymbol{x}\in \mathbb{R}^3_{++}: \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{\alpha}+\lambda \boldsymbol{\beta}, \lambda\in (0,t), \boldsymbol{\alpha},\boldsymbol{\beta} \in \mathbb{R}^3 \right\},$ where $t$ is a positive number and $\mathbb{R}^3_{++}$ implies that all coordinates in $\boldsymbol{x}$ is strictly positive. Also, for any $\boldsymbol{x'},\boldsymbol{x''}\in M$, $\boldsymbol{x'}$ are not parallel/orthogonal to $\boldsymbol{x''}$.

I am trying to find a valid metric for this set but failed. I have tried the shortest distance between the two lines (i.e., $d(\boldsymbol{x'},\boldsymbol{x''})=\left\|\frac{\boldsymbol{\beta'}\times\boldsymbol{\beta''}\cdot(\boldsymbol{\alpha'}-\boldsymbol{\alpha''})}{\|\boldsymbol{\beta'}\times \boldsymbol{\beta''}\|}\right\|$) and the volume of the tetrahedron bounded by the four endpoints of the two lines (i.e., $d(\boldsymbol{x'},\boldsymbol{x''})=\left\|\frac{\boldsymbol{\beta'}\times\boldsymbol{\beta''}\cdot(\boldsymbol{\alpha'}-\boldsymbol{\alpha''})}{6}\right\|$). But they all violate the triangle inequality condition. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

**Edit:** I also tried the angle between the lines $$d(\boldsymbol{x'},\boldsymbol{x''}) = \left\|\frac{\alpha \cdot \beta}{||\alpha||*||\beta||} \right\|=\left\|cos(\theta)\right\|,$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the two lines. But I failed to prove the triangle inequality as well.

**Edit:** I am looking for a metric that involves the $L^2-$norm.

Comment: In my opinion the notation used indicates that $M$ is a line and $\alpha,\beta$ are fixed vectors. I don't understand your usage of $\alpha',\alpha''$ etc..

Comment: @ShubhamJohri You are right! Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question. $\lambda$ should be in an interval instead of being a scalar.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri $\alpha',\alpha'',\beta', \beta''$ are different vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Do you know that a metric exists?

Comment: Angles between the lines?

Comment: @bubba Actually, I don't. But, I am trying to explore if there exists a valid metric.

Comment: @bubba Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that after I made this post, but it doesn't work as well. I have added it to the post.

Comment: I'd guess that you could regard the x's as bounded functions and then the sup norm and corresponding metric should work ?

Comment: @TomCollinge Thanks for the suggestion! I am not very familiar with the concept of bounded functions. How can we regard the $x$'s as bounded functions?

Comment: Rather than $||\cos(\theta)||$ maybe just try the angle itself $||\theta||$?

Comment: Your post has an odd feature: although you call your set $M$ a "line", the requirement that $x \in \mathbb R^3_{++}$ means that $M$ is either a ray, or a line segment, or the empty set. Was that your intention?

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry for the confusion, $M$ is a set of line segments.

Comment: $M$ as you have written it is a set of points, not a set of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function $d: M \times M  \to \mathbb R^+$ by $d(x, y) = sup_{\lambda \in (0, t)}(||(x - y)(\lambda)||) $ where $||.||$ is the $L_2$ norm in $R^3$.

Firstly, is this well defined ?
Certainly, $x - y$ is well defined for $\lambda \in (0, t)$ and $||(x - y)(\lambda)||$ is a positive ($\ge 0$) real value.
$||(x - y)(\lambda)|| \le ||x(\lambda)|| + ||y(\lambda)||$ and with $\alpha, \beta$ fixed for $x$, $t$ fixed, and $\lambda \in (0, t)$  then $||x(\lambda)||$  is bounded above as is $||y(\lambda)||$.
So, $||(x - y)(\lambda)|| $ is bounded above and therefore has a supremum.

Secondly, is $d$ a metric ?

1. $d(x, y) \ge 0$ follows from the property of $||.|| \ge 0$
2. $d(x,x) = sup(||0||) = 0$ and if $x \ne y$ then clearly, $d(x, y) \ne 0$
3. $d(x, z) = sup_{\lambda \in (0, t)}(||(x - z)(\lambda)||) $
   $= sup_{\lambda \in (0, t)}(||x(\lambda) - z(\lambda)||) $
   $= sup_{\lambda \in (0, t)}(||x(\lambda) - y(\lambda)+ y(\lambda)- z(\lambda)||) $
   $\le sup_{\lambda \in (0, t)}(||x(\lambda) - y(\lambda)|| + ||y(\lambda)- z(\lambda)||) $  by property of $||.||$
   $\le sup_{\lambda \in (0, t)}(||x(\lambda) - y(\lambda)||) + sup_{\lambda \in (0, t)}(||y(\lambda)- z(\lambda)||) $ since $||.||$ is positive
   I.e. $d(x, z) \le d(x, y) + d(y, z) $

So, $d$ is a metric.

Note, ||.|| doesn't have to be the $L_2$ norm, any norm on $\mathbb R^3$ results in a supremum metric.
This is just a specific case of a supremum metric on "bounded" functions. Your functions ($x \in M$) are bounded in terms of any norm on $\mathbb R^3$ since they are a linear combination of two vectors using a parameter $\lambda$ in a finite range $(0, t)$.

Comment: In fact, $M$ is almost a vector space. If (with $t$ fixed) you relax the conditions to allow everything to be in $\mathbb R^3$ instead of $\mathbb R^3_{++}$ then you get $0$ and inverses and $M$ is a vector space. Then, $sup(||x||)$ is a norm on $M$ and the existence of $d$ follows in the general way of metrics from norms.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! One thing to be sure about does $||(x - y)(\lambda)||$ here mean that $(x-y)$ is a function of $\lambda$?

Comment: That's correct. Now you have a metric, what are you wanting to do with it ?

Comment: I was trying to define a metric and check if $M$ is not bounded under that metric, and I think this metric is what I was looking for!

Comment: With this metric every element of $M$ is bounded, but $M$ itself is not. (Like for example the set of real numbers, each number is bounded (obviously) but the set is not).

Comment: Yes! I arrived at the same conclusion. Thanks again for your help!